# masm palindrome check output dilemma

Tags: masm

I was trying to do a palindrome check program using masm and used the below code but I always got not palindrome as output, not able to figure it out why. Please help to modify the code. The code is given below for further clarification.
Thanks in advance.

```
read macro
mov ah,01h
int 21h
endm
write macro
mov ah,02h
int 21h
endm
assume cs:code,ds:data
data segment
a db 20 dup(?)
b db 20 dup(?)
msg1 db "enter text: $"
msg2 db "reverse string is: $"
msg3 db " palindrome$"
msg4 db " not palindrome$"
data ends

code segment
start:mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
mov cx,0000h
lea si,a
lea dx,msg1
mov ah,09h
int 21h

r:read
cmp al,0dh
je l
mov [si],al
inc si
inc cx
jmp r

l:dec si
lea di,b
mov ax,cx

l1:mov dl,[si]
mov [di],dl
inc di
dec si
loop l1

l2:
mov cx,ax
lea si,b
lea dx,msg2
mov ah,9h
int 21h

w:mov dl,[si]
write
inc si
loop w

mov cx,ax
cld
lea si,a
lea di,b
l4:cmpsb
jne l5
loop l4
lea dx,msg3
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h

l5:lea dx,msg4
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

whatever is input string it gives not a palindrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing mov ax,cx use mov bx,cx as ah is used in interrupts it might cause some problems. And every where mov cx,ax is there use mov cx,bx ....now it will be correct.
It might seem funny that I answered my own question but I figured  this now and didn't delete cause it might help others from not  doing the same...